# Read/write text file from javascript in objective-c project

Tags: javascript, iphone, xcode

I am making an app for iPhone and in that I am using Javascript for making making embeded youtube in UIWebView. I want to open/read/write a file on some events from javascript and then want to use that file in objective-c code. But how can I do this? I mean at what location can I save and open the file.

I have made a file called youtubeAPI.html and calling this file from objective-c code. It opens the page successfully. Now I want to open a file and write the something everytime it changes it states, and then need to to show that file in the final result from obejective-c. Please tell me how can i do this.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
<div id="player"></div>
<script>
    //Load player api asynchronously.
    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
    var done = false;
    var player;
    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'JW5meKfy3fY',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
    }
    function onPlayerReady(evt) {
        evt.target.playVideo();
    }
    function onPlayerStateChange(evt) {
        if (evt.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) { // NEED TO ADD FILE OPERATION HERE
            setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
            done = true;
        }
    }
    function stopVideo() {
        player.stopVideo();
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

THanks
Akansha

Answer (score 1):

```
// Get file path
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];

// Read file contents
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

// Write file contents
[[content dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] writeToFile:filePath atomically:NO];
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, But i want to open/read/write something from function in JAVASCRIPT, and that need to open and get data of that file from objective-c. This will open a file in documents directory of app, but how can I access this file and write something from Javscript.

Answer (score 0):

UIWebView is a sandbox, there is no chance to do this, javascript can not access file system directly, this is what i know.
But you can do other thing.
first: save state into window object;

```
such as window.state = "someting";
```

second: read the state by Objective-C;

```
NSString *state = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.state"];
```